# Leaflet easybutton, states and color

Tags: javascript, html, leaflet

I have a bit of a weird problem. I'm still kinda a beginner with this, and altering code you don't fully understand is especially hard.

I have 2 easybuttons on a map. Both are made seperately (from different instances of the same directive).

Now they should have different colours. I have access to the colours in the place where the buttons are made, so I thought this should be really easy.

Right now (code I got from someone else), each button is actually 2 buttons alternating with showing up, and that works, except that they seem to swap places sometimes.

```
var btn1 = L.easyButton('fa-dot-circle-o', function() {
      self.trackingModeActive = true;
      map.removeControl(btn1);
      map.addControl(btn2);
    }, 'Mode 1', map);

    var btn2 = L.easyButton('fa-expand', function() {
      self.trackingModeActive = false;
      map.removeControl(btn2);
      map.addControl(btn1);
    }, 'Mode2', '');
```

What I tried first was:

```
btn1.btn.style.backgoundColor = 'red';
```

and variations of this, but it doesn't work (doesn't find a style object).
I read that instead of the symbol variable ('fa-dot-circle-o' here), you could put html code like pictures ([example](https://github.com/CliffCloud/Leaflet.EasyButton)) and thought I could put a style attribute like this but when I do this it only writes that code into the class attribute like

```
class="<img src="...">"
```

so this doesn't work for me either.

Then I read about states being possible, thought I might as well do this properly and tried this, from the easyButton website:

```
var stateChangingButton = L.easyButton({
    states: [{
      stateName: 'zoom-to-forest',   // name the state
      icon: 'fa-tree',          // and define its properties
      title: 'zoom to a forest', // like its title
      onClick: function (btn, map) {  // and its callback
        map.setView([46.25, -121.8], 10);
        btn.state('zoom-to-school'); // change state on click!
      }
    }, {
        stateName: 'zoom-to-school',
        icon: 'fa-university',
        title: 'zoom to a school',
        onClick: function (btn, map) {
          map.setView([42.3748204, -71.1161913], 16);
          btn.state('zoom-to-forest');
        }
      }]
  });
  stateChangingButton.addTo(map);
```

What I get is: ReferenceError: map is not defined
    at Object.L.easyButton (easy-button.js:55).

I put this stateChangingButton code right under the other buttons code, so I don't get why the map variable wouldn't be defined for this, but is defined for the other buttons.

I hope someone can give me a hint where/why it goes wrong. I would prefer solving the stateChangingButton problem and going from there, but I'm really curious what went wrong with the other attempts.

Edit: Just incase anyone has a similar issue, I found the reason, it is just a super old version of Leaflet apparently, and it allows only for the syntax L.easyButton('icon', function, 'text', map), nothing else. I'm not allowed to update the version unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

I use this type of code to add an EasyButton and add some style on it :

```
   backButton = L.easyButton('<span class="backButton">&larrhk;</span>', function (btn, map) {
               //ONCLICK EVENT HERE
            },
            { position: 'bottomright' });
            //Add to the map
            map.addControl(backButton);
```

I define a class to my button so i can just add some css style ( and you could change it btw) :
Css example :

```
<style> 
   .backButton{
      font-size: 3.5em;
    } 
</style>
```

This is just an example but I hope it will help you .

Comment: Thank you for trying to help. It doesn't work as it just puts the first argument (the span in your example) behind class="". But now I know why, see the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You are using "btn" parameter. It is does not exist. btn1.btn.style.backgoundColor = 'red';
Try with button like

btn1.button.style.backgoundColor = 'red';

You can see more properties that you can modify if you make a console.log(btn1);
Best regards

Alejandro